# Storing DNS servers from netsh in C

Tags: c, dns, netsh

So I've implemented a system call that should give me back the DNS servers of a given network interface (as variable, namely "interface" in my code):

```
strcpy(str, "netsh interface ipv4 show dnsservers "); 
strcat(str, interface); 
system(str);
```

Now my question: which way do you suggest to extract those DNS servers and be able to compare among them in terms of speed? I have the following function to extract the average speed as integer, so comparison between two servers should be easy, but thing is that there's no fixed number of DNS I'm encountering.

```
int average_speed(const char* ip)
{
    const char* const Delim = "Average = ";
    printf("\n    Extracting average %s", ip);

    char cmd[64];
    sprintf(cmd, "ping %s", ip);
    FILE* p = _popen(cmd, "r");
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), p))
    {
        char* s = NULL;
        if ((s = strstr(line, Delim)) != NULL)
        {
            _pclose(p);
            return atoi(s + strlen(Delim));
        }
    }
    _pclose(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be easier to use python, perl or php for that kind of command text output processing program? (hint: yes)

Comment: I guess so! In fact, I think and I've been told C is clumsy as hell, but I've been asked to do so in C as an exercise for my course...

Comment: I wouldn't say 'clumsy'. C is less forgiving than the script interpreters, and more "accurate" (meaning it does exactly what you ask it to do, interpreted scripts do many things you have no knowledge of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely DO NOT use `ping` to do that.

`ping` is the wrong tool for almost all kind of troubleshooting.

If you want to order nameservers on their speed you only have one thing to do: query them, for DNS queries, and see how fast they reply.

This is the only thing that makes sense. So you need to find out in your programming language how to do DNS queries at the lowest level and be able to time them.

And then you only start to scratch the surface and arrive at other problems to solve:

- what queries to do? if you know they handle a name, query for it; otherwise it may be accepted to query for root nameservers NS records
- you have to handle timeouts, UDP truncated replies eventually and retrying on TCP, etc.
- querying them once is fine, but topology can change; right now A might be faster than B, but maybe in 5 minutes it will be the opposite; as such any system doing that should be smart and "regularly" still probe again to see if things have changed.